# Let $f(z)$ be a non-constant analytic function on the region $D=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}| |z| \le 1\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a non-constant analytic function on the region $D=\{ z\in \mathbb{C}| |z| \le 1\}$. Suppose $|f(z)| \le1$ for all $z\in D$. Show that if $|w| <1$, then $\frac{|f'(w)|}{1-|f(w)|^2 } \leq \frac{1}{1-|w|^2}$

Comment: The $|f(w)|2$ is actually $|f(w)|^2$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I think so. That looks familiar.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error

Comment: This result is known as the Schwarz-Pick theorem.